# onChange is not working in select for react

Tags: reactjs

I just used 2 select want to capture the select change by different onChange event as below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      contPos: '',
      contAss: ''
    }
    //this.handlechange2 = this.handlechange2.bind(this)
    //this.handlechange3 = this.handlechange3.bind(this)
  }

  handlechange2 = (e) => {
    this.setState({contPos: e.target.value});
  }

  handleChange3 = (e) => {
    this.setState({contAss: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1><label>Relationship Contact Position: 
          <select value={this.state.contPos} onChange={this.handleChange2}>
            <option value="CEO">Chief Executive Officer</option>
            <option value="CFO">Chief Financial Officer</option>
            <option value="CHRO">Chief Human Resource Officer</option>
            <option value="CIO">Chief Information Officer</option>
            <option value="CMIS">C-suite minus 1</option>
            <option value="CMO">Chief Marketing Officer</option>
            <option value="COO">Chief Operating Officer</option>
            <option value="CPO">Chief Privacy Officer</option>
            <option value="CTO">Chief Technology Officer</option>
            <option value="ITDM">IT Decision Maker</option>
            <option value="LBE">Line of Business Exec</option>
            <option value="MFO">Marketing / Finance / Operations</option>
            <option value="OCS">Other C-Suite</option>
            <option value="OTHR">Other (not specified)</option>
          </select>
          </label>
      </h1>
      <h1>Relationship Contact Position: <input type='text' value={this.state.contPos} onChange={this.handlechange2} /></h1>
      <h1><label>Relationship Contact Assessment: 
          <select value={this.state.contAss} onChange={this.handleChange3}>
            <option value="CADV">Advocate</option>
            <option value="DTCT">Detractor</option>
            <option value="NTRL">Passive</option>
            <option value="PMTR">Promoter</option>
            <option value="PSDT">Passive Detractor</option>
            <option value="UNKN">Unknow</option>
          </select>
          </label>
      </h1>
      <h1>Relationship Contact Assessment: <input type='text' value={this.state.contAss} onChange={this.handlechange3} /></h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

And weird thing is 1st select(Position) can not change, always show default value, but same usage in 2nd select(Assessment) is working fine. I left 2 text to verify the select changed value, and same thing, 1st one always show default blank.
Can any one help to take a look?

btw,in the console, there is a error for 1st select, but I was confused bcos I already added onChange handler.

> Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field
>   without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If
>   the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either
>   `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Comment: you did a typo, the function you are calling is `handleChange2` but the function that is defined is `handlechange2`

Comment: Doesn't that usually throw and 'undefined' error?

Comment: @TarunDugar thanks so much!!! it blocks me long time, that is why I need a peer to review.

Comment: @FernandoG nope, that is why I can not find this typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typo as TarunDugar said, select onChange handler just used "this.handleChange2" rather than defined "this.handlechange2" and react did not show any error in console or page.Thanks again, TarDugar! it is so important to have peer coding and peer review.